# How to determine the voltage across an LR circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

Imagine a circuit with an inductor and a resistor rotating in a constant magnetic field. What is the relationship between the voltage induced across it's inductor ,resistor individually and it's generator voltage at a particular instance in time?and why?

Comment: It is not clear what is rotating.  A coil rotating in a constant magnetic field will produce an alternating voltage, so you have a voltage source in series with an inductor and a resistor.

Comment: yes, the coil is rotating

Comment: So what is the question? you have a AC generator  and a resistor as "user" easier just to take a coil with some resistance.  the smaller the resistor or the resistance of th coil the more force you need to rotate your coil.

Comment: i have added an edit, if it makes it any clearer

Comment: what about the inductor?

Comment: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electrical4u.com%2Felectrical%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F05%2Fvector-diagram-of-rl-circui.gif&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electrical4u.com%2Frl-series-circuit%2F&tbnid=ZmIH64sA_34U9M&vet=12ahUKEwjXr_OYu_fyAhVlSXwKHZtSC1MQMygAegUIARCuAQ..i&docid=RrrKwQmFoyAn3M&w=594&h=396&q=diagram%20of%20lr%20circuit&ved=2ahUKEwjXr_OYu_fyAhVlSXwKHZtSC1MQMygAegUIARCuAQ

Comment: i have posted an image of the circuit if it helps

Comment: the word coil might have caused some confusion

Comment: The word "rotation" caused great confusion. According to your figure, nothing were rotating and there was no magnetic field, but a phase diagram with a fictitious rotation angle.

Comment: Rotation of circuit components will generate an effective emf which follows from the integral $\int (v\times B).dl$ which will power the circuit as a whole. Next apply the Kirchoff's Law

Comment: could you explain in terms of phasor diagrams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give an answer based on the [link figure](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electrical4u.com%2Felectrical%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F05%2Fvector-diagram-of-rl-circui.gif&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electrical4u.com%2Frl-series-circuit%2F&tbnid=ZmIH64sA_34U9M&vet=12ahUKEwjXr_OYu_fyAhVlSXwKHZtSC1MQMygAegUIARCuAQ..i&docid=RrrKwQmFoyAn3M&w=594&h=396&q=diagram%20of%20lr%20circuit&ved=2ahUKEwjXr_OYu_fyAhVlSXwKHZtSC1MQMygAegUIARCuAQ) which OP provided in the comment, to explain the rotation of the phase diagram.

First a quick solution to the circuit with a sinusoidal applying voltage, $V_g = V_0 \cos(\omega t)$:
\begin{align}
V_R + V_L &= V_g.\\
i(t) R + L\frac{d i}{dt} &= V_0 \cos \left(\omega t\right). \tag{1}\\
\end{align}

Then assume a solution $i(t) = i_0 \cos \left(\omega t - \theta\right)$, the angle $\theta$ is called the phase delay. Plug this solution into Eq.(1), solving two unknown parameters $i_0$ and $\theta$. We have two equations, one for $\cos\left(\omega t\right)$, and the other for $\sin\left(\omega t\right)$
\begin{align}
 R i_0 \cos \left(\omega t - \theta\right) - L i_0 \omega \sin \left(\omega t - \theta\right) &= V_0 \cos \left(\omega t\right).\tag{2}\\
 i_0 R\cos\theta +  i_0 \omega L\sin\theta &= V_0; \tag{3}\\
 i_0 R \sin\theta - i_0 \omega  L\cos\theta &= 0. \tag{4}
\end{align}

Parameter $i_0$ and $\theta$ can be solve using equations (3) and (4). And according to the linked figure, the equation (2) can be interpreted as $V_R$ in the $\hat x$ axis and $V_L$ in the $\hat y$ axis, their vector sum is always equal to the voltage of the generator, which is with a phase $\theta$ ahead of the current voltage. These three vectors are coherently rotate with angular frequency $\omega$ driven by the applying alternated voltage. `This is called a phase diagram.`

Comment: Thanks..this is just what I wanted..